# NgbCarousel select does not switch the slide

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a thumbnails row to switch slides of the carousel.

The click event is working, the carousel is located correctly - I put some breakpoints in the NgbCarousel code, the passed slide id is correct and it works up to the very switching of the slide. However the slide switching is not happening.

Carousel itself works just fine - both the arrows and indicators.

Angular 6.1.0
Ng-bootstrap 3.2.0

**UPDATE**
It started working after reinstalling node modules. Though it's very laggy (10 sec for img switch with no additional network request), but that's a different story.

Template:

```
<div class="thumbs mx-auto">
  <ul *ngIf="pics">
    <li *ngFor="let pic of pics" (click)="switchPic(pic)">
      <figure>
        <img src="{{ getIconUrl(pic) }}">
      </figure>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<ngb-carousel #clotheCarousel="ngbCarousel" *ngIf="pics"
  showNavigationArrows="true"
  showNavigationIndicators="true"
  interval="0">
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let pic of pics" id="{{ stripSlash(pic.public_id) }}">
    <figure>
      <img src="{{ getThumbUrl(pic) }}" alt="Pic">
    </figure>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import _ from 'lodash';
import { NgbCarousel } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-clothe-gallery',
  templateUrl: './clothe-gallery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clothe-gallery.component.css']
})
export class ClotheGalleryComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() pics: object[];
  @Input() private thumbWidth: number = 500;
  @Input() private thumbHeight: number = 500;
  @Input() private iconWidth: number = 100;
  @Input() private iconHeight: number = 100;
  @Input() private getCurrent: object;
  // @Output() slide = new EventEmitter();
  @ViewChild(NgbCarousel) carousel: NgbCarousel;
  private currentSlide: string;
  LOG: string = 'clotheGallery';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.LOG, this.pics);
    if (this.pics && this.pics.length) {
      this.currentSlide = this.pics[0]['public_id'];
    }
    // this.slide.emit({
    //   current: this.currentPic
    // })
  }

  onSlideEvent(event) {
    // console.log('event', event);
    // this.currentSlide = event.current;
    // this.slide.emit({
    //   current: this.currentPic
    // })
  }

  get currentPic() {
    return this.currentSlide;
  }

  getThumbUrl(pic) {
    return ClotheGalleryComponent.insertResizeParams(pic, this.thumbWidth, this.thumbHeight);
  }

  getIconUrl(pic) {
    return ClotheGalleryComponent.insertResizeParams(pic, this.iconWidth, this.iconHeight);
  }

  switchPic(pic) {
    console.log(this.LOG, 'switchPic', this.stripSlash(pic.public_id), this.carousel);
    this.carousel.select(this.stripSlash(pic.public_id));
  }

  stripSlash(item) {
    return item.replace('\/', '');
  }

  static insertResizeParams(pic, thumbWidth, thumbHeight): string {
    if (!pic || !pic.url) {
      return '';
    }
    let replace = 'upload';
    let params = `${replace}/w_${thumbWidth},h_${thumbHeight},c_fit`;
    return pic.url.replace(replace, params);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to change:

```
@ViewChild(NgbCarousel) carousel: NgbCarousel;
```

to:

```
@ViewChild("clotheCarousel") carousel: NgbCarousel;
```

And use (but it may require index id):

```
this.carousel.activeId = this.stripSlash(pic.public_id);
```

instead of:

```
this.carousel.select(this.stripSlash(pic.public_id));
```

As well as:

```
<ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let pic of pics" id=" stripSlash(pic.public_id)">
```

Comment: Thank you! But nothing changed, it still does not switch.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit tricky, the selector is 'ngb-slide-X' with X the current index from 0.

Let's say you have a table, and when you click on a row, you want to update a picture.

```js
@ViewChild(NgbCarousel, { static: true }) carousel: NgbCarousel;

...

click(id: number, i: number) {
  this.carousel.select('ngb-slide-' + i);
}
```

```html
   <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let signature of signatures$|async; index as i" (click)="click(signature.id, i)" [ngClass]="{selected: signature.selected}">
    <th scope="row">{{ i + 1 }}</th>
    <td>{{ signature.date | date:'shortDate' }}</td>
    <td>{{ signature.client }}</td>
    <td>{{ signature.chauffeur }}</td>
    <td>{{ signature.signataire }}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

.....

 <ngb-carousel id="carousel" [showNavigationArrows]="false" [showNavigationIndicators]="false">
  <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let signature of (signatures$ | async)">
    <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
      <img [src]="signature.url || '/assets/img/none.png'" alt="signature.caption">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <p>{{ signature.caption }}</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Comment: btw, if ngb-slide-X doesn't suite, you can specify the id.... see https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/issues/1608

Comment: Thank you for your time, Vincent, but this is not really timely for me. Maybe I'll come back later.

Comment: The solution is in the select function just as @VincentGODIN mentioned: this.carousel.select('ngb-slide-' + i);

Answer (score 2):

I'am not sure about your ViewChild(NgbCarousel). Are you sure your console.log(this.carousel) show the carousel? By the way you can use the reference variable in your function

```
<!--pass "clotheCarousel" in the function-->
<li *ngFor="let pic of pics" (click)="switchPic(clotheCarousel,pic)">
```

and

```
//use carousel, not this.carousel
switchPic(carousel:any,pic) {
    console.log(this.LOG, 'switchPic', this.stripSlash(pic.public_id), carousel);
    carousel.select(this.stripSlash(pic.public_id));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. ViewChild returns the correct carousel - it has the exact elements I put there. However when I do like you suggested, I get `Cannot read property 'select' of undefined` error

Comment: put only one *ngIf="pics" at first or your .html -not one for carousel and another one for ul-

Comment: that's totally reasonable

Answer (score 0):

My G, let me help you:

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images" 
              [showNavigationArrows]="false"
              [showNavigationIndicators]="false"
              #carousel>
    <ng-template ngbSlide id="one">
        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
            <img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>First slide label</h3>
            <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbSlide id="two">
        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
            <img [src]="images[1]" alt="Random second slide" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Second slide label</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbSlide id="three">
        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
            <img [src]="images[2]" alt="Random third slide" />
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <h3>Third slide label</h3>
            <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>

<button (click)="onButtonClick()">First</button>
<button (click)="onButtonClick2()">Second</button>
<button (click)="onButtonClick3()">Third</button>
```

and in the .ts:

```
onButtonClick() {
  this.carousel.select("one");
}

onButtonClick2() {
  this.carousel.select("two");
}

onButtonClick3() {
  this.carousel.select("three");
}
```

Works for me amigo